# Add webservice through service reference working in vs2015 but not in 2013

Tags: c#, web-services

I received one webservice from one of our vendors, which they created using dotnet framework 4.5.1 and TLSversion 1.2. When i tried to add service reference in vs 2015 its working properly but in visual studio 2013 its not allowing to add reference.

---

There was an error downloading 'https://*/XYZ.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://*/XYZ.asmx'.
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://*/XYZ.asmx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

---

Please suggest a work around to add this web service in vs2013..

Comment: Apart from the fact that your title has it the wrong way around, have you tried "update-package" from packet manager console?

Comment: Yes i tried "update-package" also

Comment: What does `Visual studio 2013 its not allowing to add reference` mean exactly. How "not allowing"?

Comment: When i am trying to add service reference i am getting the above error... Is it possible to specify the TLS version through web.config??

Comment: Is this on the same machine or on a different one? Firewall issue perhaps?

Comment: This webservice deployed in a remote machine.. I am trying from my local machine. both vs2013 and vs2015 in same machine

Comment: Before creating the webservice object we need to specify the TLS version (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11) then only it will work...